# Stripe - does not have access to account '{{XX}}' (or that account does not exist)

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Connect and i've successfully onboarded 3 merchants.  I'm trying to generate a payment intent and i'm consistantly getting

" does not have access to account '{{acct_1FvpC4JkgwMoBOTZ}}' (or that account does not exist). "
 and yet the SECRET api key i'm using matches and hasn't changed. My platform clearly has the customer and merchant onboarded as well:

**Merchant:**

[image]
**Customer:**

[image]

**NODE.JS Initilisation:**

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(StripeKey);
```

@param CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID = acct_1FvpC4JkgwMoBOTZ

@param customerId = cus_GSe2V6snvtLlQs

**Code:**

```
exports.onDonationFinance = functions.database.ref("/Stripe/{donationId}").onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
var amount = snapshot.child("amount").val();
var email = snapshot.child("email").val();
const CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID = snapshot.child("conn_id").val();
const customerId = snapshot.child("cus_id").val();
const id = context.params.donationId;
const token = generateToken(customerId,CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID);
if(amount===0){
    amount =250;
}else if(amount ===1){
    amount =500;
}else if(amount ===2){
    amount =1000;
}else if(amount ===3){
    amount =1500;
}
const applicationFee = Math.round((amount/100)*1.45);
stripe.customers.create({
    source: token
  }, {
    stripe_account: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID,
  });
(async () => {

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        amount: 1000,
        currency: 'gbp',
        application_fee_amount: applicationFee,
        customer: customerId,
      }, {
        stripe_account: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID,
      }).then(function(paymentIntent) {
        // asynchronously called
        const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret
            const donationStripeCleanup = admin.database().ref(`Stripe/${id}`)
            return admin.database().ref(`Stripe/${id}/clientSecret`).set(clientSecret);

      });



  })();
});
```

**Android Code:**

```
  extraParams.put("setup_future_usage", "off_session");
                                        confirmparams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams.createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params,dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), null, false, extraParams);

                                        stripe = new Stripe(MakeUserPayment.this, PaymentConfiguration.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getPublishableKey());
                                        stripe.confirmPayment(MakeUserPayment.this,confirmparams);
                                        secretListener.removeEventListener(this);
```

@Param connectedAccount = test mode client ID

**To generate the token:**

```
function generateToken(customerId, connectedAccount){
    stripe.tokens.create({
        customer: customerId,
      }, {
        stripe_account: `{{${connectedAccount}}}`,
      }).then(function(token) {
        // asynchronously called
        console.log('Token :', token);
        return token;
      }).catch((error) => {
                return console.log('Token Error:', error);
           }); 

}
```

Token error i'm recieving: The provided key `'sk_test_hB****************************EYq3' does not have access to account '{{acct_1FvpC4JkgwMoBOTZ}}' (or that account does not exist). Application access may have been revoked.`

Does anyone have any idea where i'm going wrong here? The end use case is: customer makes payment to merchant, my platform takes an application fee of that amount.

Comment: Please console log token value

Comment: added, i'm getting a token error

Comment: Ok, i am checking

Comment: Please check the setting of secret key

Comment: The secret key is the test one from the accounts API...i think it's fine

Comment: Please check customer id permission in web panel??

Comment: Please tell me before that customer is deleted ??

Comment: no it hasn't been deleted, how do i check it in the web panel?>

Comment: Sorry no, i posted it on here for a reason :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're literally sending `{{${connectedAccount}}}` which turns into `{{acct_ABCXYZ123}}`, which is not correct; try this instead:

```
stripe.tokens.create({
    customer: customerId,
  }, {
    stripe_account: `${connectedAccount}`,
  }).then(function(token) {
```

Comment: Thanks Lomas, i've since solved the issue and fixed the problem that's above...i've now included the android code (which was where the problem was)...if you can tailor your answer to fix the problem with it i'll give you the correct answer :).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - the initial error I described is still in your node.js code.

Comment: It may be that you're storing the Stripe Account ID with those in your database?

Comment: Sorry Lomas, i meant to change that in the Node.js code, your answer is correct but doesn't solve the problem (changing it still presents the same issue).  The issue in the end was in the Android Java code, Stripe needs to be initiated (using the consutrctor) with the connected stripe ID when using Stripe connect.

Comment: Lomas, i retract my last statement, your answer does indeed solve the issue i'd originally brought with the question. my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in ruby because of the same (silly) mistake.

I had

```rb
Stripe::Account.create_login_link('account.id')
```

but should have had

```rb
Stripe::Account.create_login_link(account.id)
```